# Redirect 301 .htaccess Redirect Error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have re-vamped a website and I'm attempting to ensure all of the old, deleted directories are redirected to the new pages. For example, I have a directory called /category/ and want it redirected to http://website.com/interiordesign.html. The root website is still the exact same. I've implemented some coding in the .htaccess file, but it is giving me a redirect error.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /category/ http://website.com/interiordesign.html
Redirect 301 /interior-design-portfolio/ http://website.com/interiordesign.html
Redirect 301 /contact-location/ http://website.com/contact.html
Redirect 301 /tag/ http://website.com/blog.html
```

I have the remove / rule in place, as I found when I didn't implement that, it was taking the user to interiordesign.html/ and with the slash, it didn't work.

Apologies for my poor coding, this is not my area of expertise.